# Auth0 makes infinite tabs in chrome if i run my shinyapp

Tags: shiny, auth0, shinyapps

I wanted to implement a login system using Auth0, it was easy to use and configure but when I run the app locally or through port 8080, auth0 keeps opening millions of tabs and I have to shut it down, I found someone with the same issue in Auth0 community but no answers for a month now in the link below:

https://community.auth0.com/t/r-shiny-app-opens-infinite-tabs-when-using-auth0-locally-on-port-8100/115601

I also tried using app.R and ui.R/serve.R both have same issue, I followed this tutorial while also using their sample app and it didn't work, I made sure that I followed all steps and redid them a lot but same issue.

I followed this tutorial below:

[https://curso-r.github.io/auth0/#:~:text=Because%20RStudio%20is%20specialized%20in,page%20and%20won't%20work](https://curso-r.github.io/auth0/#:%7E:text=Because%20RStudio%20is%20specialized%20in,page%20and%20won%27t%20work).

From the writing of the tutorial, it did say that shiny viewer will not work so open it using browser like chrome or Firefox, and that shiny viewer will have blank page indicating it works but not on this viewer (which happened to me, so I know my implementation is correct) but once it opens chrome it just opens millions of tabs and I have to close the shiny viewer in order for chrome to stop opening tabs.

Here's my code for testing auth0:

```
library(shiny)
library(auth0)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:10)
  })
}


auth0::shinyAppAuth0(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue, and for me the fix was to tell RStudio to run shiny apps in a browser by default. When the app was attempted to be viewed within RStudio, this problem was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right corner of your RStudio, Click on ‘Run App’, and select ‘Run External’.

This fixed this issue for me. It will directly open the app in the Browser and the Auth0 window should show up without opening multiple zillions of tabs.

-Venki